# Porting third-party python packages onto Snowpark

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to port the Googletrans package onto Snowflake snowpark, and use it in a UDf.

As the package is unsupported by Snowpark natively, I zipped up the package folder, and uploaded it to a snowpark stage at `@DWH.MY_SCHEMA.PACKAGES` stage. My code then looks like this

```
import 
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf
import googletrans

session = snowpark_session('DWH', 'MY_SCHEMA')
session.add_import("@PACKAGES/googletrans.zip")
session.add_packages("snowflake-snowpark-python", "pandas", "numpy", "scikit-learn", "spacy")

@udf(name='MY_FUNCTION', replace=True, is_permanent=True, stage_location="@MODEL_STAGE")
def myFun(text:str) -> bool:
    translator = googletrans.Translator()
    /.../
    return True
```

Here, I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Any idea on what additional steps I would need to take to make Snowflake recognize the package?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the example provided in [this article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Importing-3rd-party-Python-packages-containing-non-Python-files-using-Snowflake-stages-when-creating-Python-UDFs) to import your external libray via a Python UDF.

Basically you can use `/tmp` to unzip the package and then import it. Here is the content of a UDF importing `pycountry` package:

```
create or replace function PROCESS_COUNTRY_TEST(country_value varchar)
   returns varchar
   language python
   runtime_version = 3.8
   handler = 'process_country'
   packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
   imports = ('@sergiu_stage/pycountry.zip')
   as
$$
import fcntl
import os
import sys
import threading
import zipfile

# File lock class for synchronizing write access to /tmp
class FileLock:
   def __enter__(self):
      self._lock = threading.Lock()
      self._lock.acquire()
      self._fd = open('/tmp/lockfile.LOCK', 'w+')
      fcntl.lockf(self._fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX)

   def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
      self._fd.close()
      self._lock.release()

# Get the location of the import directory. Snowflake sets the import
# directory location so code can retrieve the location via sys._xoptions.
IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME = "snowflake_import_directory"
import_dir = sys._xoptions[IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME]

# Get the path to the ZIP file and set the location to extract to.
zip_file_path = import_dir + "pycountry.zip"
extracted = '/tmp/pycountry_pkg_dir'

# Extract the contents of the ZIP. This is done under the file lock
# to ensure that only one worker process unzips the contents.
with FileLock():
   if not os.path.isdir(extracted + '/pycountry'):
      with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as myzip:
         myzip.extractall(extracted)

sys.path.append(extracted + '/pycountry/src')

import pycountry

def process_country(country_value) -> str:
    return str(pycountry.countries.search_fuzzy(country_value)[0].alpha_2)
    

$$;
```